# how data is structured in join clause in one to many relation

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

i want an answer to this question as i have search the internet and not found. the question is 
"How should data be structured to facilitate JOIN clauses in a one-to-many relationship? What about a many-to-many relationship?"

Comment: IN the same way, you need to have something relateable in the tables.

Comment: To create a one-to-many, you need to add the primary key from the one side to many side as a column. To create many-to-many you need a middle table which contains the primary keys from many to many tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of one-to-many you should insert the id of the referenced item in the table that is on the *many* side.

### one-to-many case

A person can own many cars but a car is owned by only one person.

In a relational database this is translated with the creation of the `person_id` inside the `car` entity. In this way you can retrieve all the cars owned by a person with a simple join.

In case of a many-to-many relationship, you need to create a bridge table between the two entities.

#### Get owners of the Mazdas query Example

```sql
SELECT name, surname
FROM car JOIN person ON car.person_id = person.id
WHERE car.brand = 'mazda'
```

### many-to-many case

Example:

Let's suppose that the requirement has been changed and a car can be owned by many people.

This is translated by adding a new bridge table (e.g. person_car) that has the following columns:

- `person_car_id`
- `car_id`
- `person_id`
- `other_columns_that_could_map_the_relationship` (e.g. `is_the_main_owner`)

#### Get owners of the Mazdas query Example

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT name, surname
FROM car JOIN person_car ON person_car.id_car = car.id JOIN person ON person_car.person_id = person.id
WHERE car.brand = 'mazda'
```

If you see here you can map many-to-many relationship between the two entities and perform a double JOIN (passing through the bridge table) to retrieve the elements.

Comment: Makes Sense. Thanks